# Error loading Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I've a crystal report in Asp.net MVC. When I run on my local machine, it works fine. But when I deploy it on server. It gives error

> The type initializer for
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an
>   exception.

I've added the the following dll to the bin folder while deployment.

```
-- CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
-- CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc
-- CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
-- CrystalDecisions.Shared
-- CrystalDecisions.Web
-- CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms
```

I've installed CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_2 on server.

Answer (score 0):

Finally issue is solve.
If  we install CRRuntime of 64 bit. Then during publishing we have to select PLATFORM TARGET to x64, rather then Any CPU.

Thanks and Best Regards.